# jQuery selector not working / click trigger is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a site with 3 "desktops" (divs), and clicking on a `td` in the top bar the one of the "desktops" comes in

```
$("#bar td").click(function() {
    var hash = $(this).data("sDiv");
    $(hash).animate({right: "0px")}, 400);
});
```

And till here, everything works fine.

Then I added this script to make one of the `td`s selected (changing the color) when someone opens the page with an hash.

```
if(location.hash.length !== 0) {
    $("[data-sDiv='" + location.hash + "']").addClass("selected");
}
```

And everything works fine too.

After that, in the previous `if`, I added another script to trigger a click on the `td` when someone opens the page with an hash.

```
$("[data-sDiv='" + location.hash + "']").trigger("click");
```

But with this code the click is not triggered, but the rest of the code is working fine. I have no errors in console, so I can't understand what am I doing wrong, why is this not working?

**Edit** (adding informations):

This is my nav bar

```
<div id="bar">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td data-sDiv="#desk1"><a data-bash="42548">Desktop 1</a></td>
            <td data-sDiv="#desk2"><a data-bash="42CA1">Desktop 2</a></td>
            <td data-sDiv="#desk3"><a data-bash="42FC9">Desktop 3</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this are my "desktops"

```
<div id="desk1">Content</div>
<div id="desk2">Content</div>
<div id="desk3">Content</div>
```

Both `Desktops` and `Navbar` are direct childs of `body`

Comment: Have you tried the following ?

$("[data-sDiv='" + location.hash + "']").click();

Comment: Yes @DanielRosano , this doesn't work too, same result. no errors.

Comment: What's the relation/hierarchy between `td` and `div/desktop`? can you post the `html` too?

Comment: Yes @AshrafPurno, I've edited the question

Comment: `html` looks fine. One possibility is that you are triggering the `click` event before actually binding the event. Is your `if` block comes before `$("#bar td").click(function() { ...`?

Comment: _Great Scott!_ yes, the problem was this! I knew that in javascript doesen't matter where a var/functions is declared you can call it anywhere...but jQuery isn't like so, right? Anyway, thank you @AshrafPurno, if you want you can answer my question so I can accept it :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :) but `jQuery` has nothing to do with this. This is how `javascript` works. You are actually not declaring any `var/function`. You are   `triggering` and `binding` events. I have added the bit as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that you are triggering the click event before actually binding the event.

Check the ordering of your `if` block and `$("#bar td").click(function() { ...`